# GNU screen: Launch command in session without changing window to it

Tags: bash, sh, system-administration, gnu-screen

We have an attended-upgrade script which launches `apt-get update && apt-get upgrade` simultaneously on all our administered systems. Ideally, we'd want to launch them all inside a screen session. When I do it like this:

File: upgrade.sh

---

```
for host in $ALLHOSTS
do
    some_commands_which_take_considerable_time
    screen -X screen sh -c "ssh $host \"apt-get update && apt-get upgrade\""
done
```

---

`$ screen ./upgrade.sh`

, it works, but as there are new windows arriving on the session, they are automatically being switched to. Instead, I'd rather have a version where the active window is fixed unless contained process quits or I switch manually using `^A n`.

Bonus points if there is a possibility to preserve windows with exited processes, but keeping them separate from windows with active processes.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks to CodeGnome, I'll probably go with tmux as I believe there is no way to do it with screen (that's unfortunate, really!).

To give a better sketch of how it can be used:

```
#!/bin/sh

tmux new-session -d -s active
tmux new-session -d -s inactive
tmux set-option -t active set-remain-on-exit on

for host in $ALLHOSTS
do
    tmux new-window -d -t active: -n upgrade-$host "
        ./do_upgrade_stuff.sh $host
        tmux move-window -s active:upgrade-$host -t inactive:
    "
done
```

Answer (score 2):

You can do this with [tmux](http://tmux.sourceforge.net/). For example:

```
# Start a session named "apt-get" and leave it running in the background.
tmux session-new -d -s apt-get

# Preserve windows with inactive processes.
tmux set-option -t apt-get set-remain-on-exit on

# Start a new window without switching to it. You can also do this from
# within a running tmux session, not just outside of it.
tmux new-window -d -t apt-get -n upgrade-$host \
     "ssh $host 'apt-get update && apt-get upgrade'"
```

Note that you can have multiple windows with the same name, or modify the argument to the -n flag for unique names. The tmux application doesn't care.

As an example, you could name each window "upgrade," but that would make it difficult to identify your SSH sessions at a glance. Instead, this example appends the value of the *host* variable (populated by your for-loop) to each window name. This makes it easier to navigate, or to programmatically close windows you are no longer interested in. This is especially valuable when you have a lot of unclosed windows displaying terminated processes.

Overall, the syntax is a little cleaner and more intuitive than GNU screen's for this sort of task, but your mileage may vary.

Comment: +1 Thanks for this answer, I have made my script based on it. See my answer below, I will accept it as soon as I'm allowed to.

Answer (score 0):

W/r/t preserving windows after a subprocess exits, one possibility is to invoke the `zombie` command in your screen config file(s), which requires that you specify two keyboard characters that kill or resurrect the window, respectively. E.g.:

```
zombie KR
```

Then, `K` would kill a window whose subprocess has terminated, while `R` would attempt to relaunch the subprocess in the same window. Note that, in a zombie window, those keys are captured at the top level (i.e., do not precede them with your normal screen control character prefix sequence).

In order to prevent automatic switching to a newly created window, try altering your invocation of screen to something like the following:

```
screen -X eval 'screen sh -c "ssh $host \"apt-get update && apt-get upgrade\""' 'other'
```

Comment: Thanks, I know about zombie, but that will not keep windows with exited processes separately. The `other` thing is a hack and I probably wouldn't even consider it as a last resort solution (for example, it changes the window that is targeted when I issue an `other` by pressing `^A ^A` myself).